# Loading test namespaces

Tags: testing, clojure, namespaces

I have a Clojure project where I want to programatically examine all namespaces to see if they contain tests (as defined by `clojure.test/deftest`)

I can successfully identify the tests if they are loaded (via the `:test` metadata tag on the vars) but many of the tests are ini .clj files that are not automatically loaded by the project and these don't get detected.

Is there a way to load all namespaces in the current project in order to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just look at the source for `lein test`? IIRC it uses builtitude to find and load all namespaces on the classpath.

Comment: Nice idea! With a bit of experimentation I managed to make bultitude do exactly what I want. Thanks!